# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException is occure even though the element is visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException is occuring even though the element is visible.

I am find an element using xpath and sending data in the field by using send keys. This is done to all the fields in the form.But , when control comes to specific field , it throws  this error . validated Xpath, it is correct.Element is not added dynamically(input/text box)

../selenium-2.34.0/libs/guava-14.0.jar has no source attachment is the error.What does this mean

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other element with same id? May be that element is hidden. This might be one of the cause. Also try adding some sleep time or try debugging with `isDisplayed()` method

Comment: when isDisplayed() method is used, it is displayed false, but element is visible in the form. Same field is working fine in other tabs.

Comment: Do you need to use scroll bar to move to the element? or it is displayed in the visible portion of screen?

Answer (score 0):

If there is an iframe in the application , u need to navigate to it using driver.switchto(). Unless you navigate to it, u will be getting similar result .